# How can i return a Response from restTemplate put api?

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, resttemplate

i'm trying to retrieve an put api exposed response as a Response object 
the valid url http://localhost:8081/**nameoftheapplication***/{id}/validateToExportFile

the return format example when i tested it is like : 
[image]

i'm using restTemplate exchange because the put just do the update,the method works fine when i change the return type to String but i want to return a Response for other treatment the method that i'm using actually is

```
public Response validateToExportFileExchange(ReturnValidationDetails returnValidationDetails) {
    String validationURL = (validateToExportURI + "/" + returnValidationDetails.getReturnId() + "/validateToExportFile");
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.add("Accept", "*/*");

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));

    messageConverters.add(converter);

    resttemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    HttpEntity<ReturnValidationDetails> validateToExportFileExchangeEntity = new HttpEntity<>(returnValidationDetails, headers);

    return resttemplate.exchange(validationURL, HttpMethod.PUT, validateToExportFileExchangeEntity,
            Response.class).getBody();
}
```

and i have this Exception :
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface javax.xml.ws.Response] and content type [application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet]
thx in advance for your help

Comment: Why are you using `javax.xml.ws.Response`? That is for JAX-WS why use that here. Instead receive the result and directly stream the response back.

Comment: the api that i'am consuming returns a Response that include inputStream i cannot change it

Comment: You are mapping to the `Response` yourself, that has nothing to do with the API you are consuming.